# Dovecot/Sieve adds extra / in file path

Tags: postfix, centos6, dovecot, sieve

I'm putting the finishing touches on a Postfix/Dovecot/Postgres server (before attempting to rebuild it from scratch based on notes alone), and I have everything working except for one thing I can't figure out- I can't get the user sieve files to be read.

The error is as follows:

```
Debug: sieve: user's script path /home/mail/jane//.dovecot.sieve doesn't exist (using global script path in stead)
```

Everything else works flawlessly, except for the user script path. I followed the instructions on half a dozen blogs/guides, used man pages, and checked various other forums to get this far, but I can't solve this last bit.

I have the following configuration files thrown up on Pastebin for reference:

-[Postfix main.cf](http://pastebin.com/zR9vqtwL)
-[Postfix master.cf](http://pastebin.com/2bQ2r0dC)
-[Dovecot dovecot.conf](http://pastebin.com/bJYucnS5)
-[Dovecot dovecot-pgsql.conf](http://pastebin.com/LdUmdd90)
-[Postgres user table layout](http://pastebin.com/8Gzn5DVD)

I've tried using any combination of ~, ., and / to go up a directory level with the sieve parameter, but it either treats it as an absolute path (which won't work, because each user will be different), or just adds it to the script path above (/home/mail/jane//~/.dovecot.sieve).

Comment: what happens if you remove the trailing `/` in `maildir` from within the user table?

Comment: It will probably break all the other references that postfix uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue with a workaround- I changed the

```
"sieve ="
```

setting to

```
"sieve = /home/mail/sieve_scripts/%u.sieve"
```

and then created "user@mycompany.com.sieve" files for the accounts under:

```
"/home/mail/sieve_scripts/"
```

Not as elegant as I wanted it to be, but sometimes simple is better.